# How to populate dropdownistFor from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I need help populating a drop down list of states in my MVC application using razor views:

In my model I have a sate property:

```
 public SelectList State
    {
        get { return new SelectList(StateDictionary, "Value", "Key"); }
    }
```

Here is a shortened version of the state dictionary

```
public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> StateDictionary = new 

    Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"ALABAMA", "AL"},
            {"ALASKA", "AK"},
            {"AMERICAN SAMOA", "AS"},
            {"ARIZONA ", "AZ"},
            {"ARKANSAS", "AR"},
            {"CALIFORNIA ", "CA"},
            {"COLORADO ", "CO"},
            {"CONNECTICUT", "CT"},
            {"DELAWARE", "DE"},
            {"DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA", "DC"},
            {"FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA", "FM"},
            {"FLORIDA", "FL"},
            {"GEORGIA", "GA"},
};
```

In my Razor view I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State,new{@class="col-lg-2 control-label"})
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,Model.State,new {@class="form-control" })

                    </div>
```

When I try to access my view I keep getting a "Object reference not set" error

How can I populate the dropdownlist from this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add to your model a property

```
public string SelectedState { get; set; }
```

then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, Model.State, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Then on submit you will get the selected state value on the model's `SelectedState` property

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 



Source Error: 


Line 126:                        <div class="form-group">
Line 127:                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State,new{@class="col-lg-2 control-label"})
Line 128:                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState,Model.State,new {@class="form-control" })
Line 129:                      
Line 130:                        </div>

Comment: Could you post the code on your controller that creates the model and call the view, you should be doing something like return View(model); It seems that the model is null

Comment: I tried passing the model and got the same error:   [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
           RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: That's strange, I am testing your code and seems to work, there should be something else, if you post your controller, and model code maybe we can see if there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**Your Model**

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public SelectList Values { get; set; }
}
```

**Your Controller**

```
public ActionResult YourMethod()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"ALABAMA", "AL"},
        {"ALASKA", "AK"},
        {"AMERICAN SAMOA", "AS"},
        {"ARIZONA ", "AZ"},
        {"ARKANSAS", "AR"},
        {"CALIFORNIA ", "CA"},
        {"COLORADO ", "CO"},
        {"CONNECTICUT", "CT"},
        {"DELAWARE", "DE"},
        {"DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA", "DC"},
        {"FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA", "FM"},
        {"FLORIDA", "FL"},
        {"GEORGIA", "GA"},
    };

    var model = new YourModel
    {
        // Choose one of the below options for displaying either the long or short name in the dropdown
        //Values = new SelectList(dictionary, "value", "key")
        Values = new SelectList(dictionary, "key", "value")
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**Your View**

```
@model YourModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a property like this:

```
public string State { get; set; }
```

in Controller set your Dictionary in ViewBag

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "Key", "Value"))
```

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items